# How to convert a Html Page containing SVG Graphs and other html elements into PDF/Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I've tried using canvg,html2canvas and canvas2image. But, I didnt get the expected result. Is there any other plugins to achieve it?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: K is there any other way to do it??

Comment: Maybe [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate place for your question.

Comment: It's just a poc..so am trying to do with open source libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET, which it appears you do, then you might try [EVO HTML to PDF Converter](http://www.evopdf.com/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx). I've had success using it in the past, and it supports SVG.

Comment: Is is possible to do via Javascript?

Comment: Last I checked, there were no client-side JavaScript libraries for generating a PDF (although that may very well have changed since then). As far as I know, you'd have to set up a web service that takes the HTML (or gets it via the URL of the page to convert), converts it to a PDF, and then streams it back to the client. That's the approach we used, anyway.

Comment: Even for saving as jpeg..should I do the same thing?

Comment: I've never used it to generate an image, but it appears to be a supported feature. From their website: _Convert web pages, HTML strings to raster image formats_